# nginx return 404 if I send e-mail using django

Tags: django, email, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am trying to send e-mail, using simple contact form.
On local development it works, but on production I get 404 error and no e-mails are sent.

What I have:
Nginx, Gunicorn, Django

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'www.example.com']

EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'googleapppassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

access_log

```
"POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 404 198 "http://example.com/contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
```

UPDATE:

nginx config

```
upstream example.com {
    server localhost:12345 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log  /path/to/access.log;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    root /path/to/static_content;

    location ~ ^/(static|media)/ {
        access_log off;
        expires 60d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /path/to/static_content/static/html;
    }

    location ~ ^/(static|media)/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://example.com;
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

error.log

```
2015/03/21 15:36:04 [error] 28486#0: *272 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.65.125.145, server: example.com, request: "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:12345/contact/", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/contact/"
```

Comment: 404 means your request isn't passed properly to backend, please check your nginx config.

Comment: Update with nginx configuration and error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was hard to solve.

I had to edit my /etc/hosts file and restart services

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost example.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 example.com
```

Afer this I've restarted services

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
$ sudo service nginx restart
$ sudo service postfix restart
```

Now it's working superfast without any errors.

P.S. postfix is in the list, because I was trying to solve the issue by using postfix and not smtp.gmail.com, but postfix is not required.
Also, take a look at /etc/hostname and /etc/mailname